# Multiply each element of a column with other elements of the same column

Tags: matlab

If A is the matrix i have and i wanted to get the matrix B by multiplying each element of a column with each other element of the column (one by one). And store the result in a separate matrix. So if A is 3x3 matrix will give rise to B that is 9x3 matrix.

I have used the following loop code but it just gives the result of the final iteration.

```
for j = [1:3]
    for i=1:3 
       B(:,j)= A(i,j) .* A(:,j);
    end
end
```

Could you please suggest how I can do it. Thanks

```
 A= 1 3 7
    2 4 8
    3 5 9

B=  1 9 49
    2 12 56
    3 15 63
    2 12 56
    4 16 64
    6 20 72
    3 15 63
    6 20 72
    9 25 81
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the ["outer product"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product). For a column vector `v` with `n` elements, the outer product is of size `n`-by-`n`:

```
o = v*v'
```

where `o(ii,jj)` is the product of `v(ii)*v(jj)`.

To do it for all columns of a matrix, you can use [bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun):

```
o = reshape(bsxfun(@times,permute(A,[1 3 2]),permute(A,[3, 1, 2])),[],size(A,2))
```

For an example input matrix `A = [1 3 7;2 4 8; 3 5 9]` the output `o` is:

```
 1     9    49
 2    12    56
 3    15    63
 2    12    56
 4    16    64
 6    20    72
 3    15    63
 6    20    72
 9    25    81
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try it.

Comment: Will it work for a bigger 500-by-90 matrix to form a 250000-by-90 matrix. I am trying to understand your code in the meantime, so just asked.

Comment: @user5933603 code-wise speaking it can work with any 2D matrix `A`. I suspect you'll run into memory issues with very large matrices.

Comment: ok  i will try and reduce the size or process it on a Linux cluster with more memory. Thanks  again!